# Trigger a click event on a Google Map Marker by clicking on a button and a seperate JS file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Map API v3 anf jQuery 1.11.0.

I have a Google Map in the following div-

```
<div  id="googleMap" class="map_div"></div>
```

The map has 4 markers and it's click event is added by this way in JS-

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',
    (function(marker, i)                        //Adding Click Function
    {
        return function()
        {
            //Add Your Customized Click Code Here
                alert(locations[i][3]);
            //End Add Your Customized Click Code Here
        }
    })(marker, i));
```

Now I have a button in another part of the html (**outside map**) like this-

```
<button id="3">Click Me</button>
```

Now I want to add a on click event which will trigger click event of a map marker with index of 3.

So, I have JavaScript in HTML like this-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#3").click(function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[3], 'click');
    });
});
</script>
```

But it is not working. I think it can't select the marker with jQuery.
Because I have previously selected the map with jQuery like this-

```
google.maps.event.trigger($("#googleMap")[0], 'resize');
```

To re-size the map.

So, can anyone help me to have the **Selector script of a Google Map Marker in jQuery**.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's what you mean?? 
flow my examples: 
I have use `google.maps.event.trigger(markers[2], 'click');`

and it worked. I thing wrong from your event click of marker.
[My examples](http://jsfiddle.net/ksgqbrzt/)

Javascript

```
    var tam = [16.3,108];
    var toado = [[16.5,108.5,"https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxFoh469eOsZQkuPOLpZn3R6yyIExkZCxOxf4ywfeY3v330EwP3Q"],
                [16.3,108,"https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxFoh469eOsZQkuPOLpZn3R6yyIExkZCxOxf4ywfeY3v330EwP3Q"],
                [16,107,"https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxFoh469eOsZQkuPOLpZn3R6yyIExkZCxOxf4ywfeY3v330EwP3Q"],
                [23,105,"https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxFoh469eOsZQkuPOLpZn3R6yyIExkZCxOxf4ywfeY3v330EwP3Q"]]; 
    var markers = [];

    function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {   
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(tam[0], tam[1]),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions); 


        for (var i = 0; i < toado.length; i++) {
            var beach = toado[i];
            urlimg =  beach[2];
            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                        urlimg,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        new google.maps.Size(15, 15));                              

            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[0], beach[1]);

            markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                draggable : true,
                animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });
            var ismove = true;
            (function(marker,i){
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){ 
                alert(toado[i][2]);
                //infowindow.open(map,this);
                }); 
            }(markers[i],i));

        }
        //setMarkers(map, beaches); 
    }
    window.onload = initialize;
```

//Html

```
  <body>
    <input type="button" id="btn-click" value="Click"/>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn-click").click(function(){
            google.maps.event.trigger(markers[2], 'click');
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: google.maps.event.trigger(markers[2], 'click'); did it for me with no problem, thanks

Comment: This does not work in clustered markers (one of the group markers) situation. Please share suggestion if you have. Thanks.

Comment: Grouped makers isn't a maker in item list