# Show Google Maps InfoWindow OnLoad

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How can you show Google Maps InfoWindows OnLoad of the document? Everything works perfect. The InfoWindow pops up on click but I am not 100% sure how to solve the problem, that it shows up on load...

Please find my code below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var infowindow = null;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            initialize();
        });

        function initialize() {
            var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(52, 10);

            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 5,
                center: centerMap,
                scrollwheel: false,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("maps"), myOptions);

            setMarkers(map, sites);
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "loading...",
                maxWidth: 60
            });

            var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
            bikeLayer.setMap(map);
        }

        var sites = [
            // array here
        ];

        function setMarkers(map, markers) {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var sites = markers[i];
                var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: siteLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: sites[0],
                    zIndex: sites[3],
                    html: sites[4]
                });

                var contentString = "Google Maps";

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: **trigger marker click :3**

Comment: flow answer **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497023/trigger-a-click-event-on-a-google-map-marker-by-clicking-on-a-button-and-a-seper/28497602#28497602**

Comment: Call infowindow.open to open the infowindow while loading, and the close it when you are done.

Comment: Can anybody please provide an working example for the code above?

Comment: Which infowindow did you want opened on load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a separate info window for each marker, and you can open them all.  Please see the code snippet for more details:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #maps {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
  <script>
    var infowindow = null;
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    function initialize() {
      var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(52, 10);
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: centerMap,
        scrollwheel: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("maps"), myOptions);

      setMarkers(map, sites);

      var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
      bikeLayer.setMap(map);
    }

    var sites = [
      ["this is a title", 52, 10, 10, "<div>This is the first site</div>"]
    ];

    function setMarkers(map, markers) {
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var sites = markers[i];
        var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: siteLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: sites[0],
          zIndex: sites[3],
          html: sites[4]
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: sites[4],
          maxWidth: 60
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          infowindow.setContent(this.html);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="maps"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a tip for your question. this is click to marker by code javascript with function **trigger** after map loaded.

**example**

`google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
       google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click'); //with marker is global validate
});
</scrip>
```

**UPDATE**, **if you have a marker**, when **initialize();** called **google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');** add it after **initialize();**
//How to declare marker to global

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var infowindow = null;
        var marker = null; //declare marker to global
        ...
</script>
```

**UPDATE**,  **if you have markers** with code add markers :) you change to

```
var _markers = [];
function setMarkers(map, markers) {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var sites = markers[i];
                var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
                _markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: siteLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: sites[0],
                    zIndex: sites[3],
                    html: sites[4]
                });

                var contentString = "Google Maps";

                google.maps.event.addListener(_markers[i], "click", function () {                    
                    infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                    infowindow.open(map, this);
                });
            }
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            initialize();
            for(var i = 0, count = _markers.length; i<count; i++){
               google.maps.event.trigger(_markers[i], 'click');
            }
        });
```

flow this question to view full example with trigger click

[Trigger a click event on a Google Map Marker by clicking on a button and a seperate JS file with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497023/trigger-a-click-event-on-a-google-map-marker-by-clicking-on-a-button-and-a-seper/28497602#28497602)

with handle event **map loaded**, you can use **titleloaded** event

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
  // Visible tiles loaded!
});
```

Comment: I'm failing the whole time, even with your example. How and where do I have to to put it into my code :(

Comment: Thanks, but how can I make "marker" global if it's only called in the SetMarker function?

Comment: I don't see how you show how I can make my setMarker function "marker" variable global... your onload script tells me undefined marker, of course.. :(

Comment: Can you please have a look at my code and show me what to do? I understand your way of solving it, but I do not understand how to re-develop my construction

Comment: Yes, all windows on load :(

Comment: you have array of markers, just for all it and **trigger** event to a marker :3

Comment: Can you please just show me how? I browsed the web for 2 days, already tried all snippets, adjusted everything... "just trigger" sounds easier as it is

Comment: I don't understand what to do? Can you not just copy and paste my snippet and show me where to put your snippet?

Comment: it says here: _markers[] = new google.maps.Marker({ Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]

Comment: ah sorry about that. change to **_markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker...** it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling InfoWindow.open() method inside your click event. To open the info window onLoad you have to call it inside the initialize function. Or you can add it inside addDomListener(). 
Refer: [Same kind of discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416160/listening-for-the-domready-event-for-google-maps-infowindow-class)

Comment: Sorry but the "same kind of discussion" is about an onclick event not onload.

Comment: Yes. To add a method to your onload function, you can try this infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      // Here call InfoWindow.open() method
});

Comment: But how can I adjust it to the piece of code I have? I don't see how I can solve it...